Swift Regex Error: Cannot Convert 'Regex<(Substring, Substring, Substring)>' to 'Regex<AnyRegexOutput>' When Matching Patterns
I'm working on a Swift class that utilizes regex for pattern matching, but I'm encountering an error when trying to initialize the Regex type in my custom class.
class code:
import Foundation

class Challenge {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let regex: Regex<AnyRegexOutput>
    var isComplete: Bool
    
    init(title: String, description: String, regex: Regex<AnyRegexOutput>, isComplete: Bool = false) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.regex = regex
        self.isComplete = isComplete
    }
}

Code with the Error
I am trying to create an array of Challenge instances like this:
var dailyChallenges =  [
    Challenge(title: "Update Title",
              description: "set a new website title",
              regex:  /<title>(?!webview<\/title>)(.*?)<\/title>/),
    
    
    Challenge(title: "Add Image",
              description: "add an image with a source URL",
              regex:  /<img(\s.*\s|\s)(src="http.+?")/),
]

The Error Message
However, I am receiving the following error:
Cannot convert value of type 'Regex<(Substring, Substring)>' to expected argument type 'Regex<AnyRegexOutput>'

Arguments to generic parameter 'Output' ('(Substring, Substring)' and 'AnyRegexOutput') are expected to be equal

and :
Cannot convert value of type 'Regex<(Substring, Substring, Substring)>' to expected argument type 'Regex<AnyRegexOutput>'

Arguments to generic parameter 'Output' ('(Substring, Substring, Substring)' and 'AnyRegexOutput') are expected to be equal

Question
How can I modify my class to use regex patterns that can match any number of substrings, so I can avoid this conversion issue?
